# Constant truncated to integer

Tags: floating-point, go, syntax-error

The following GO program gives the error:

```
./fft.go:13: constant -6.28319 truncated to integer
./fft.go:13: cannot use -7 * k / N (type int) as type float64 in assignment
```

Program:

```
package main

import (
    "math"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world ",math.E)

    var k, N int = 1, 10
    var ans float64 = 0
    var c float64 = (-2.0 * math.Pi * k) / N
    x := make([]float64,N)
    for i := 0; i < len(x); i++ {
        x[i] = 1
    }
    ans = 0
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        ans += x[i] * math.E
    }
    fmt.Println(ans)
}
```

Why cant I use an `int` in a type of `float64` ?

Comment: I really dig these VERY nice golang error messages ... they include people in the discussion, not just machine chatting with machine ... what a joy compared to writing in any other language ... and proactive which makes writing golang code that much more fun

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Replace

```
var c float64 = (-2.0 * math.Pi * k) / N
```

by

```
var c float64 = (-2.0 * math.Pi * float64(k)) / float64(N)
```

To quote the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

> Conversions are required when different numeric types are mixed in an
>   expression or assignment. For instance, int32 and int are not the same
>   type even though they may have the same size on a particular
>   architecture.

Go uses static typing and doesn't automatically convert between numeric types.  The reason is probably to avoid some errors.  For instance, what value and what type should `float64(2.5) * int(2)` yield?  Should the result be `int(5)`?  `int(4)`?  `float64(5.0)`?  In Go, this isn't an issue.  The Go FAQ has [more to say](http://golang.org/doc/faq#conversions) on this.

---

@jnml points out that, in this case, the following is enough:

```
var c float64 = -2 * math.Pi / float64(N)
```

Comment: `c := -2*math.Pi/float64(N)` is enough

Comment: In this case, yes.  But I think question is about typing, not about getting this particular program to work.  So, although `c := ...` is better code, I think it confuses the answer a bit.

Comment: Ehm, ignore the 'c := ' part, that's just out of habit. The point was that two of the three instances  of `float64` are superfluous and `k*floatConst` can use integer `k` - it's an "ideal" number.