# Why int(0.1) is error but x := 0.1; y := int(x) is correct in golang

Tags: go, int

In Golang

why 
`var y = int(0.1)` have a error
but `x := 0.1; y := int(x)` is ok?

Comment: The first one is converting a constant, the other one a variable. The are different rules when converting contants. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions **Constants:** `int(1.2) // illegal: 1.2 cannot be represented as an int` **Non-Constant:** x can be converted to type T if `x's type and T are both integer or floating point types.`

Comment: See related / possible duplicate: [Does Go compiler's evaluation differ for constant expression and other expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444852/does-go-compilers-evaluation-differ-for-constant-expression-and-other-expressio/39445372#39445372)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GO lang - constant truncated to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151199/go-lang-constant-truncated-to-integer)